# Heading for a CSV file containing matrix

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

My application produces a CSV containing a matrix using csv::writematrix $matrixname $file. This prints only my matrix to the CSV file. How can i put a title to this csv file each time the file is written?

```
set outfile [open "$csvfile" w]
set template [path/to/template/for/matrix/file.csv]
#populate the template with data
set matrix [loadmatrix $template]
csv::writematrix $matrix $outfile
close $outfile
```

Comment: Please show the relevant bits of your code

Comment: Insert a (title) row at the top of your matrix? Write a separate one-row matching-number-of-columns matrix (that contains the titles) first and then write your data as at present before closing the file handle? What's the most obvious thing that might possibly work?